# Excel vba download file with random file extension

Tags: asp.net, excel, vba, internet-explorer, download

I am trying to write a code to automatically download files from a website by Excel vba.  I know there are plenty of posts regarding this topic but no luck so far. The first few lines of code go like this:

```
Sub testing()

Dim ie as object

Url _base = "http://www..../download.aspx?id="
Num = cells(1,1).value
Set ie = createobject ("internetexplorer.application")
Ie.visible = true

For i = 1 to num
   Url = url _base & i
    ....
```

Then I become clueless.  The problem is that winhttp seems to only download csv files, and urldownloadtofile requires a solid url path ending with the file extension. However, my case is the link is redirecting to the actual file location (no extension shown), and also the file could be any extension such as pdf, jpg, and doc.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, editing answer to fold in feedback, three different ways to make an HTTP request and it seems you are looking to trap a redirect which is status codes 300-303, 307-308.  Try this and provide feedback as to whether or not you are redirected.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestGetFileFromWeb()
     Call SaveTextToFile(GetFileFromWeb2("http://www.wikipedia.com"), "c:\temp\wikipedia2.txt")
     Call SaveTextToFile(GetFileFromWeb3("http://www.wikipedia.com"), "c:\temp\wikipedia3.txt")

     '* placed last because it gives "Access Denied" Run-time error '-2147024891   &h80070005
     'Call SaveTextToFile(GetFileFromWeb1("http://www.wikipedia.com"), "c:\temp\wikipedia1.txt")
     Call SaveTextToFile(GetFileFromWeb1("http://www.bbc.com"), "c:\temp\bbc.txt")

End Sub

Private Function SaveTextToFile(ByRef sText As String, ByVal sFileName As String) As Boolean


    '* Requires Tools ->References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim txtOut As Scripting.TextStream
    Set txtOut = fso.CreateTextFile(sFileName, , True)
    txtOut.Write sText
    txtOut.Close
    Set txtOut = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    SaveTextToFile = True

End Function

Private Function GetFileFromWeb1(ByVal sURL As String) As String

    '* Requires Tools->References->Microsoft Xml, v.6.0

    Dim xHTTPRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xHTTPRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    xHTTPRequest.Open "GET", sURL, False
    xHTTPRequest.Send
    Debug.Assert WasRedirected(xHTTPRequest.Status)

    GetFileFromWeb1 = xHTTPRequest.ResponseText

End Function


Private Function GetFileFromWeb2(ByVal sURL As String) As String

    '* Requires Tools->References->Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1

    Dim oWinHttp As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Set oWinHttp = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    oWinHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
    oWinHttp.Send
    Debug.Assert WasRedirected(oWinHttp.Status)
    GetFileFromWeb2 = oWinHttp.ResponseText

End Function


Private Function WasRedirected(ByVal lStatus As Long) As Boolean

    'http://qnimate.com/redirection-and-duplicate-content-in-websites/
    'There are many types of HTTP redirection.
    '
    '300 Redirect or Multiple Choices
    '301 Redirect or permanent redirect
    '302 Redirect or Found or Temporary Redirect
    '303 Redirect or See Other
    '307 Redirect or Temporary Redirect
    '308 Redirect or Permanent Redirect
    'HTTP refresh header

    WasRedirected = (lStatus = 300 Or lStatus = 301 Or lStatus = 302 Or lStatus = 303 Or lStatus = 307 Or lStatus = 308)

End Function


Private Function GetFileFromWeb3(ByVal sURL As String) As String

    '* Requires Tools->References->Microsoft Xml, v.6.0

    Dim xHTTPRequest As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Set xHTTPRequest = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    xHTTPRequest.Open "GET", sURL, False
    xHTTPRequest.Send
    Debug.Assert WasRedirected(xHTTPRequest.Status)
    GetFileFromWeb3 = xHTTPRequest.ResponseText

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Meaden for your help.  Just wondering whether your code requires to know the file extension beforehand?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Did you try it?

Comment: Just tried it for a ppt file. Turned out it downloaded as a 3kb file and cannot be opened by PowerPoint.  Then I changed the extension to txt and opened successfully, but the content was the source code of the webpage instead.

Comment: Yes it is. It ends with  ".aspx?id=(a random number)"

Comment: so why issue a second request to the address referenced in the response to the first?

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite get your question. What do you mean by a second request?

Comment: Ok, sorry let me try again...  so if you are redirected I think you get a redirect status code (300-303, 307-308) and if so then you ought to be able to inspect the redirect URL.  I have changed my code samples.